# AdaptativeRandomForest after pickle

Tags: pandas, numpy, machine-learning, pickle, random-forest

Has anybody ever have a problem applying AdaptativeRandomForest from the skmultiflow on a deserialized dataframe? I apply df.values to get array like object so i can fit that into my model but i keep getting the error TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'

```
def modelCreator (X_train_list,y_train_list,X_test_list,y_test_list,partial_fit, n_estimators ,drift_method = None, warning_method = None):
    accuracy = []
    precision = []
    recall = []
    f_1 = []
    for i in range(len(X_train_list)):
        X_train = X_train_list[i].values
        y_train = y_train_list[i].values
        X_test = X_test_list[i].values
        y_test = y_test_list[i].values
        arf  = AdaptiveRandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = n_estimators, drift_detection_method = drift_method,
                            warning_detection_method = warning_method)
        if partial_fit:
            model = arf.partial_fit(X_train,y_train)
        else :
            model = arf.fit(X_train,y_train)  
        prediction = model.predict(X_test)
        accuracy.append(accuracy_score(y_test,prediction))
        precision.append(precision_score(y_test,prediction))
        recall.append(recall_score(y_test, prediction))
        f_1.append(f1_score(y_test, prediction))
   
    return accuracy,precision,recall,f_1
```

That is the code that creates the models , and i do get X_train , y_train , X_test and y_test from .pkl file.

Since I before already trained this model using df.values this should work , but for speeding up the script run i needed to separate the creation of the dataframe list , from the actual training of the model . That is why i get the data as a .pkl